# PHPUnit Laravel Hash not available

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-facade

I have a Unit test in Laravel for testing an API call that looks like this, however I am getting the following runtime error when running it:

```
RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set.
```

I'm creating a user in the setup method, with the intent to delete it again in the tearDown() method, then run my auth test.

Firstly, is there a better way of doing what I want? For example Mocking a user without touching the database? And secondly, how do I set a 'facade root' or what does that error mean exactly? I've tried not bothering to hash that particular field for the purposes of creating a Dummy user, but the error then seems to move to the model, where (again) the Hash facade class is used.

Is there any additional steps to setup the environment so these facades can be used in testing?

Thanks in advance.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

/*
* Make sure the structure of the API call is sound.
*/
public function testAuthenticateFailed()
{

  $this->json('POST', $this->endpoint,
        [ 'email' => 'test@test.com',
          'password' => 'password',
        ])
         ->seeJsonStructure([
             'token'
  ]);

}

//create a user if they don't already exist.
public function setup()
{
  $user = User::create([
      'company_id' => 9999,
      'name'=>'testUser',
      'email' => 'test@test.com',
      'password' => 'password',
      'hashed_email' => Hash:make('test@test.com'),
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Is you test extending Laravel's TestCase?

Comment: @RossWilson yep,  extends TestCase

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to use this instead:

```
\Hash::make('test@test.com'),
```

It's a good idea to use `bcrypt()` global helper instead of `Hash::make()`

Also, add this to `setUp()` method:

```
parent::setUp();
```

Comment: Class 'Hash' not found is returned. Note the import statement is present, use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash as Hash; doesn't work either.

Comment: that returns A facade root has not been set.

Comment: You forgot to call  `parent::setUp();` in `setUp()` method.

Comment: Yep that's what it was @Alexey

Comment: by the way, what is the purpose of -> parent::setUp()    thou it works, newbie at phpunit here. tia!

Answer (score -1):

1. You could use the `DatabaseMigrations` or `DatabaseTransactions` trait that comes with Laravel so you don't have to delete the User manually.
2. You could add a Mutator to your User class, which will automatically hash the password when a User is created.

```
    // https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators

    public function setPasswordAttribute($value) {
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
    }
```